# Opening thousands of cURL handles without running into problems? (PHP)

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I need to use cURL in PHP to make **thousands** of cURL requests to an API.  My currently plan is to do these in parallel with curl_multi_() functions.  Basically to execute all of the thousands of cURL requests in parallel at once.

I've heard that you can run into memory problems opening too many handles, which can run into fatal errors.  How can avoid that and still make my URL requests as fast as possible?

If I need to limit the number of cURL requests to be made at a time, what's a good # to set the limit at?

Background: I'm on shared hosting with Godaddy right now which does fine with cURL requests, though I haven't tested it with thousands of parallel requests.  In the future I'll be on a [Rackspace Cloud Site](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/sites) which can handle a modest load.

This huge # of cURL requests is a once per year thing, not a part of daily site operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like an architectural problem.  Why do you need to make thousands of requests at the same time?  Is that sort of parellism going to do any good, or are you just going to accidentally DOS (Denial-of-Service) some poor suspecting web service/API?

Assuming you're not pounding a single remote server, you still need to worry about how many connections your local box can handle.  There are only so many ports you can use outgoing, and they're measured in the low tens of thousands.  It's not hard to hit that limit if you're going nuts opening connections.  Anyone who's overdone load testing with apachebench knows this.

PHP is not a great tool for this kind of thing -- and I'm a guy who does 90% PHP.  There's no threading, and it's memory intensive.  If you want 1000 PHP processes in parallel, you're going to need more than one machine.  Your typical PHP process is going to consume around 10-20 megs of memory, unless you tune the hell out of it (probably at compile-time.

You say this happens once a year.  That makes me think it might not be necessary be all that parellel.  What if you only had 24 or 36 parallel processes?

That said, here's how I'd probably approach this.  PHP will probably work fine, and if you run into the memory inefficiency issues, you can swap out just one part.  You want two, more-or-less asynchronous queues, and a pair of processes that work on them:

- A "fetch queue" - a work queue of HTTP requests that need to get made.  They perform the request and stick the data in the processing queue (see next bullet).
- A "processing queue" a work queue that works through whatever the HTTP responses contain.  As is queue gets processed, it can add new items to "fetch queue"
- Some process (or a couple dozen) that run in parallel working on the fetch queue.  Parallelism is nice here, since you have so much latency due to the network.
- Some process that chews on the "processing queue" - it's not clear that parallelism will help here.  All this processing happens locally, and can probably be a simple loop.

Comment: Your point that I should rethink this method actually rings true.  In some ways its not strictly necessary for me to use the API.  I'm going to accept your answer for those who would benefit from it in addition to myself.

Comment: Good - this is just a typical case of "divide and conquer" -- break the work down into different little jobs, and then focus on getting that bunch of jobs to run efficiently.  If you had to do this every day, you could scale  the solution I outline up to a bunch of machines, some fetching, and some processing, in some ratio that you'd need to figure out by trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Rolling Curl](http://code.google.com/p/rolling-curl/). I used it to extract links and web page content from multiple webpages pages. I've no idea about how will this work on server as I've only experience on local machines.

Answer (score 1):

All the things suggested by timdev are wrapped up in Zebra cURL  https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_cURL.  you can pass an array of URLs and it will queue up some (default 10) in parallel and then call them and pass a result object into a callback.  From the github docs:

```
    <?php
        function callback($result) {
            // remember, the "body" property of $result is run through
            // "htmlentities()", so you may need to "html_entity_decode" it
            // show everything
            print_r('<pre>');
            print_r($result->info);
        }
        require 'path/to/Zebra_cURL.php';
        // instantiate the Zebra_cURL class
        $curl = new Zebra_cURL();
        // cache results 60 seconds
        $curl->cache('cache', 60);
        // get RSS feeds of some popular tech websites
        $curl->get(array(
            'http://rss1.smashingmagazine.com/feed/',
            'http://allthingsd.com/feed/',
            'http://feeds.feedburner.com/nettuts',
            'http://www.webmonkey.com/feed/',
            'http://feeds.feedburner.com/alistapart/main',
        ), 'callback');
    ?>
```

It's really fast and sweet on memory usage

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info really. How much bandwidth will be used for each connection ? unless its a couple bytes you will choke most connections opening that many sockets at once. Even if your account is capped, your 1000 socket idea will be bottle-necked and rendered pointless. Why cant you open 100 sockets and loop as it one completes. this is very fast